# spring security 3.1- redirect to login page with context url

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security3.1 with name space configuration. I want to redirect to login page if I enter the URL in browser up to the context path, instead of full URL of the login page.

For example, `http://xxx:8080/context/` instead `http://xxx:8080/context/login.html`

I am able to display login page with complete URL `http://localhost:8080/context/login.html`

I have tried the following code:

```
<http auto-config='true' authentication-manager-ref="authentication-manager" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
 <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html"/>
 <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>


....
```

I added a `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` entry in order to redirect to login page also but it seems not working.

Comment: Can you explain what seems not working? Are you getting a blank page? How did you configure the url-patterns?

Answer (score 3):

The standard configuration will redirect to the login page if you add some security constraints. So use

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login />
</http>
```

and you will be redirected to the login page automatically if you request any URL. You don't need to configure an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Make sure you can get basic examples working before trying to customize things.

Also your configuration isn't valid - you've only posted the opening element of the `http` block. If you still can't get it to work, please post the full configuration which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Correct form: <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()"/> If for example I wan't redirect to register user page without isAuthenticated() method will perform.